# How to achieve method level synchronization while using ExceutorService

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to achieve method level synchronizaton within an ExecutorService executing new Thread inside loop. Below is a method which generates a random number. "synchronized" keyword doesn't help here as synchronization is bound to object; but here I am creating multiple objects of my Thread. Is there any way by which I can achieve synchronization on method in each Thread while using ExecutorService. Please refer to below code for more understanding.

```java
package test;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            executorService.execute(new SampleTest());
        }
        executorService.shutdown();

        while (true) {
            if (executorService.isTerminated()) {
                Thread.sleep(2000L);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

class SampleTest implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(generateCorrelationId());
    }

    public synchronized String generateCorrelationId() {
        String messageId = null;
        try {
            GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
            messageId = (new Integer(gc.get(Calendar.DATE))).toString();
            messageId = messageId + (new Integer(gc.get(Calendar.MONTH))).toString();
            messageId = messageId + (new Integer(gc.get(Calendar.YEAR))).toString().substring(2);
            messageId = messageId + (new Integer(gc.get(Calendar.HOUR))).toString();
            messageId = messageId + (new Integer(gc.get(Calendar.MINUTE))).toString();
            messageId = messageId + (new Integer(gc.get(Calendar.SECOND))).toString();
            messageId = messageId + (new Integer(gc.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND))).toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return messageId;
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
24112123910149
24112123910149
24112123910149
24112123910149
24112123910149
24112123910149
24112123910149
24112123910149
24112123910149
24112123910151
```

Here, I am getting only one unique number but I want 10 unique numbers from each Thread. Please suggest.

Comment: We can always synchronize on a specific object. In order to synchronize all calls of a method of different objects, we have to synchronize on a common object, e.g. a static field of the class.

Comment: Could you explain to us what problem you are trying to solve in general with this code?

Comment: Also, why do you use synchronization if you don't share any state - all your variables are local.

Comment: @Barracuda I think that this is exactly the problem. OP wants - in essence - that at most one thread at one point in time can generate the output, thus "guaranteeing" that each thread generates a different output. The mutual exclusion is implicit - each thread should "generate" a different timestamp if you so will.

Comment: @Turing85 - you understood the problem correctly. I want the same.

Comment: @Pushpak, may I ask how exactly are you going to use this? Because,even if you can, it does not seem like a good idea.

Comment: @Barracuda - I have to generate a unique number which shouldn't be used previously in my system. That's why I have used Calender based unique number generation. The method generating that unique number can be accessed by any Thread in system. I have to ensure that only one Thread should be able to access and lock that method at that instance so that no two or more Threads are able to generate same number.

Comment: @Pushpak Your usecase looks like a need for Threadsafe singleton, and synchronize the generateUniqueNum method with running counter. which can generate unique value irrespective of being called from multiple threads. You can use `AtomicInteger` or `AtomicLong` with current system time to get unique value with no collision. Also consider using snowflake mechanism to generate unique values in a distributed environment

Answer (score 0):

The particular problem with `generateCorrelationId` is that although you synchronize it, it is a different method for each thread (if you convert it to static, it takes very little time and all calls come in at the same millisecond).

If you change the method to static and add a delay, you will see that they are already all different.

```
public static synchronized String generateCorrelationId() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    ...
```

However, unless you have a very special requirement, this is not the right way to do it.

The usual way is to use a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) (in java [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)).

Another way that would involve synchronization is to use an [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html), for example:

```
class SampleTest implements Runnable {
    static AtomicInteger uniqueCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(generateCorrelationId());
    }

    public synchronized String generateCorrelationId() {
        return Integer.toString(uniqueCounter.incrementAndGet());
    }
}
```

Comment: not related to the "synchronization" question, but you could also look into [snowflake](https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/a/2010/announcing-snowflake). i remember reading sth like _"if you need unique ids, first thing that should come to your mind is snowflake"_